# UPDATE Table with CTE update always with the same value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update, common-table-expression

I'm trying to anonymize a single column in a database through data shuffle.

I created this query but when I run it it update the column `FirstName` always with the same name:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

;WITH TCE_Shuffled
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY [BusinessEntityID]
            ) AS ORIG_ROWNUM
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY NEWID()
            ) AS NEW_ROWNUM
        ,*
    FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]
    )
UPDATE [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]
SET FirstName = t2.FirstName
FROM TCE_Shuffled t1
JOIN TCE_Shuffled t2 ON t1.ORIG_ROWNUM = t2.NEW_ROWNUM

SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]

ROLLBACK TRAN

SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]
```

Here you can see that the column `FirstName` as the same value:

| BusinessEntityID | PersonType | NameStyle | Title | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13353 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | M | Griffin |
| 13354 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | NULL | Diaz |
| 13355 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | J | Xu |
| 13356 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | NULL | Sun |
| 13357 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | NULL | Zhu |
| 13358 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | R | Gao |
| 13359 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | NULL | Hayes |
| 13360 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | NULL | Ma |
| 13361 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | G | Price |
| 13362 | IN | 0 | NULL | Erik | M | Liang |

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pet peeve: [The semicolon (`;`) is a statement terminator](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-the-semicolon-is-a-statement-terminator/) *not* a "beginningator". It goes at the *end* of **all** your statements, not at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. Not terminating your statements properly is deprecated, so you should really try to get into the habit of properly terminating your statements now, so that your code doesn't break if the change is every forced through.

Comment: I didn't know that. I saw a lot of query like this on the internet. I will share this tip, thank you Larnu

Comment: Yes, a lot of people put it at the start of CTE's when posting online because people who write (in my opinion) poor SQL copy said code and then complain it's wrong and doesn't work, where as the actual code that is wrong is the person who copied it.

Comment: The reason you were having an issue is that you were cross joining everything again with `UPDATE [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]` because you were not referring to the `FROM` clause

Comment: @Charlieface, is there another way to script this update?

Comment: @forpas has given you the correct answer, I was just explaining the root cause of the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName
FROM TCE_Shuffled t1 JOIN TCE_Shuffled t2 
ON t1.ORIG_ROWNUM = t2.NEW_ROWNUM;
```

Comment: that was magical. I wish you a very nice day